# Change IMEI Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'd like to change IMEI to my Android Studio emulator (Nougat 7.0)
I tried root it but it not worked.
I don't want to be identified as Android SDK like in this image

[image: AVD detection]